# I'm writing a Mastermind (like) game with Ruby. I'm having trouble with the clues. They work on one attempt but not the next and so on

Tags: ruby

When I run the code it works, sort of.  It will take your guess and check it but the clues for correct number but wrong position and correct number don't seem to work as they are supposed to.  It will tell me I have 1 or more right but in the wrong position and then take it away the next time even though the number was used again. I don't think the correct clue works at all either.

So here is my code and I'll also have a Repl link at the bottom.

````
class Mastermind
  def initialize
    @answer = create_code
    @guess_number = 12
    @winner = false
  end

# this takes user input and determines if it's valid or invalid or the actual code (winner) #
# it also determines how many attempts left and displays to player #   

  def ask_what_you_guess
    while @guess_number > 0 do
      break if @winner
      p "#{@guess_number.to_s.rjust(2)} attempts left: "
      input = gets.chomp.split("")
      if guess_is_vaild?(input)
        win = guess(input)
      else
        puts "Invalid input! Please try again!"
      end
    end
    
    game_over

  end

# method for guessing the code and what happens after  #

  def guess(number)
    if number == @answer
      @winner = true
    else
      x = get_x(number)
      y = get_y(number)
      puts "Please try again, #{x} Correct/#{y} Wrong Spot."
      @guess_number -= 1
    end
  end

# method for the end of game / different messages for winner or loser #

  def game_over
    input = nil
    until ["y", "n"].include?(input)
      if @winner
        print "You won! Would you like to try again? [Y/N]"
      else
        print "You lose, this time!  Would you like to give it another try? [Y/N]"
      end
      input = gets.chomp.downcase
    end
    restart_game?(input)
  end

# gives player option to restart the game at the end #

  def restart_game?(input)
    case input
    when "y"
      true
    when "n"
      false
    end
  end

# creates code for player to break #

  def create_code
    code = []
    until code.size == 4 do
      number = (rand(6) + 1).to_s
      code << number unless code.include?(number)
    end
    code
  end

# Checks to see if entry is valid #

  def guess_is_vaild?(input)
    if input.size == 4 && input.all? { |e| "123456".include? (e) }
      return true
    else
      return false
    end
  end

# method(s) to take user input and place into correct place #

  def get_y(number)
    y = 0 
    number.each_with_index do |e, i|
      y += 1 if e == @answer[i]
    end
    return y 
  end

  def get_x(number)
    x = 0
    number.each_with_index do |e, i|
      x += 1 if e != number[i] && number.include?(e)
    end
    return x 
  end
end

puts "***********************************************\n" \
     "*CodeBreaker: can you guess the right number? *\n" \
     "*   Guess a 4 digit number composed of 1-6.   *\n" \
     "*    Y means how many numbers are correct.    *\n" \
     "*    X correct but in the wrong position.     *\n" \
     "***********************************************"

     restart = true
     while restart do
       mastermind = Mastermind.new
       restart = mastermind.ask_what_you_guess
     end
     puts "Thanks for playing CodeBreaker, Code Master!"```

Here is a Repl link: https://replit.com/@realMNohgee/mastermind#main.rb

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thank you!
````

Comment: This uses neither Rails nor a gem so you should not have those tags.

Comment: Should `x += 1 if e != number[i] && number.include?(e)` be `x += 1 if e != @answer[i] && @answer.include?(e)`?

Comment: Also `puts "Please try again, #{y} Correct/#{x} Wrong Spot."` instead of `puts "Please try again, #{x} Correct/#{y} Wrong Spot."`.